# Button to another Page with Sencha Touch

Tags: button, extjs, hyperlink, touch

I just created a little Homepage with Sencha Touch. Now I want use the buttons to link to another site/page. How can I do that? I don't want to use the standard Tab bar.

```
Ext.define('RMA-App.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'RMA-App'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Event anlegen',
                ui: 'normal',
                iconCls: 'add',
                iconMask: 'true',
                iconAlign: 'top',
                margin: '5 5 5 5'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Events anzeigen',
                ui: 'normal',
                iconCls: 'list',
                iconMask: 'true',
                iconAlign: 'top',
                margin: '5 5 5 5'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to view with a handler

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Events anzeigen',
    handler: function() {
         var someRootContainer = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#someRootContainer");
         someRootContainer.removeAll();
         someRootContainer.add(Ext.create(yourTargetView));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think I inarticulate it. I want to link to another view not to another URL. Is it similar like this?

Comment: What you are looking for is a card panel, look up a tutorial on it on the main sencha website.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to your scenario. But Reimius is right, as long as you stay inside your app this is just a self implemented card layout, without any animations.